# Generate new page dynamically by user (Firefox OS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-os

I'm developing my first app for Firefox OS and and yet I have many doubts. I want to manage multiples profiles in this app, for example: dad's profile, mom's profile, etc. in the same app.

The first time, exist 2 pages: 'welcome's screen', and doing left-swipe, the 'new profile screen'. If the user creates a dad's profile, the app should see like this:

Welcome's Screen | Dad's Profile | New profile

And if he adds another profile:

Welcome's Screen | Dad's Profile | Mom's Profile | New profile

My question is: how i can generate new pages for Dad, Mom's profiles.... dynamically?. I know a little about HTML, CSS and JavaScript but i don't know if a need another lenguage to do i want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your family profiles are not stored in the remote database just use html. If the profiles are stored in the remote database then you have to use server-side lang. such as PHP.

Comment: All is stored in local, so i had thought use the 'localStorage''s option of JavaSript (i don't know if exists a better way to this).

Comment: If the app is only for firefox OS, then just use localStorage. However if it is not, then javascript is actually not recommended.

Comment: Perfect, because it's only for Firefox OS. Now, i just need to know generate a new page, or a new 'html block' for new profiles. If i create 3 html pages: welcome.html - profile.html - new profile.html. And if i have two profiles, i change the information of profile.html by javascript?

Comment: Just change the information by javascript.